# Are there any performance differences between std::copy and the container's copy constructor?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, copy-constructor, std

`std::copy` is a more general approach since it can handle containers with differing value types (e.g. copy from `std::vector<float>` to `std::vector::<double>`). But when the value type is the same for both containers, does it matter whether I use the copy constructor instead of `std::copy`?

Comment: std::copy has preconditions (eg.: the target range is valid). The  assignment of a container to another does not imply these preconditions. You actually compare different use cases, which are not comparable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't worry about performance, they should all be super close. Instead:

- If you're creating a new container that's a copy, use the copy constructor or two-iterator constructor (if different element types).
- If you're replacing (assigning) an existing container, use the appropriate assignment operator *or* `assign` member.
- If you're replacing a subset of elements, use `std::copy`.

By accurately representing what you're trying to do, you give the compiler the most possible information to optimize its code (for example constructing directly from an existing container it can pre-allocate exactly the right about of memory).

Answer (score 1):

One potentially important difference is when you have a situation where you are able to invoke the move constructor rather than the copy constructor (e.g. when the object you are copy constructing from is an rvalue, such as the return value of a function). If you have such a situation, you definitely want to make sure you take advantage of it by move constructing or move assigning rather than using std::copy.

Basically this is just another reason to follow Mark B's advice.

Comment: Well, then there's the *algorithm* [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) in case you want to move a subset of the elements.

Comment: Using std::move on the elements of a vector is not the same as move constructing / move assigning the vector itself. It may be much more expensive.

Comment: It may, but generally copying the elements are the most expensive part.

Comment: If you move construct / move assign from another vector of the same type, there is no moving or copying of the elements. If you use std::move you may get a cheaper move operation if one is available but if not you will fall back to a copy. Compare move constructing a vector of 1 million std::array<int, 1000> to using std::move for example.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I was thinking more in the domain of copying/moving a *subset* of elements.